# How to return Multiple Parameters using json in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have four fields in my view `CustomerName`, `ContactPerson`, `Email`, `MobileNo`

`CustomerName` , `ContactPerson` are Cascading Dropdown and `Email` and `MobileNo` are textboxes.

If I select the `CustomerName` related `ContactPerson` will load automatically load in `ContactPerson` dropdown.

If i select the `Contactperson` the `ContactPerson` related `Email` and `PhoneNo` will load automatically in `Email` and `PhoneNo` textbox. I did this all task completely and all are working fine. Now what i need is i wish to reduce the code .

**My Controller Code**

```
    public JsonResult GetCustomers()
     {
        return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }

    public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);
        var customercontacts = (from a in db.CustomerContacts where a.CustomerID == Id select a);
        return Json(customercontacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

  public JsonResult GetEmailByContactPersonID(Guid CustomerContactId)
     {
      var ContactID = db.CustomerContacts.Where(i => i.CustomerContactID == CustomerContactId).Select(i => i.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
      var contact1 = (from p in db.Contacts where p.ContactID == ContactID select p).FirstOrDefault().Email1;
        if (contact1 == null)
        {
            var contact2 = (from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == ContactID select a).FirstOrDefault().Email2;
            contact1 = contact2;
        }
        return Json(contact1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }

 public JsonResult GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID(Guid CustomerContactId)
    {
        var ContactID = db.CustomerContacts.Where(i => i.CustomerContactID == CustomerContactId).Select(i => i.ContactID).FirstOrDefault();
        var mobile1 = (from pn in db.Contacts where pn.ContactID == ContactID select pn).FirstOrDefault().Mobile1;
        if (mobile1 == null)
        {
            var mobile2 = (from a in db.Contacts where a.ContactID == ContactID select a).FirstOrDefault().Mobile2;

            mobile1 = mobile2;
        }
        return Json( mobile1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**My View Code**

```
   @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })

   @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })

   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "control-label" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MobileNo, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text",disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly"  })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNo)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" ,disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

**My Json Code**

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(function () {
      $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "VisitorsForm")',{
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });

          $('#CustomerID').change(function () {
        $('#CustomerContactID').empty();

        $.ajax(
           '@Url.Action("GetContactPersobByCustomerId", "VisitorsForm")',{
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
                success: function (data) {
            $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                 $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');
                   });
                  }
               });
            });
        });

  $("#CustomerContactID").change(function () {
           alert("hhh");
    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetEmailByContactPersonID", "VisitorsForm")',{
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: { CustomerContactID: $("#CustomerContactID").val()
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Email").val(data);
                             }
                         });
                     });

   $("#CustomerContactID").change(function () {
     alert("hhh");
    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetPhoneNoByContactPersonID", "VisitorsForm")',{
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: { CustomerContactID: $("#CustomerContactID").val()
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {

                $("#MobileNo").val(data);
            }
          });
        });
```

See my coding i wrote separate  json and jquery , ajax code for `Email` and `PhoneNo`. I feel it is not good . I wish to short my code. I want to pass multiple parameter using json. I want to pass the `Email` and `phone` while selecting the `ContatcPerson` in `ContactPerson` dropdown. it also effect  performance of my application. please any one give solution and suggestion for my problem.

Advance Thanks..

Comment: You just need one `$("#CustomerContactID").change(function () {` which calls one controller method (say) `GetContactPersonDetails()` which returns both values as an anonymous object (see Andreas Pilavakis's answer) and then use `$("#Email").val(data.email);` and `$("#MobileNo").val(data.phone);`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return an object from your controller that contains all the information that you need?

Any object serialized to Json can be returned as a JsonResult.

You could even do anonymous types like:

```
var details = new { email = "test@test.com", phone = "1234567"};
return Json(details);
```